# Stub http-request in integration testing of js-app run with selenium

Tags: node.js, selenium, vue.js, mocking, integration-testing

I do integration testing in my Vue SPA with `webdriverio` and `cucumberjs`.
When loaded my application does request to get data from api-server.

In my tests I'd like to modify / stub data returned from api-server without 'touching endpoint' (i.e. deny request and return my json).

`Nock`, `moxios` and others won't work as my application is loaded with selenium.

I am aware about `json-server`, `wiremock`, but I don't want to modify my source code (urls) just for testing purposes.

Ideally `selenium` / `webdriverio` should intercept request or add custom code to webpage and return my json.

What options do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium was designed for end-to-end testing and it doesn't provide any mean to mock/stub the requests.

But there're some ways to do so:

- Launch the browser on a proxy server which will intercept the requests and mock or redirect them (see [browsermob-proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy)).
- Launch the browser with a web extension to intercept and mock the requests.
  You can either code your own web extension or you can use one like [Wiremock extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wiremock-extension/ikiaofdpbmofgmlhajfnhdjelkleljbl) if you are using Chrome/Chromium.
- Inject some Javascript in the page to hook [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).
  Since Selenium doesn't provide a way to inject the code before page is loaded, it will only work on the requests triggered upon mouse/keyboard input.